# Monitor not sending notification on missing data datadog

Tags: datadog

facing some issue with notification when data is missing.
We receive metrics every 1 hour.
We have set a monitor to notify if no metrics received for 70 minutes.
But even if we fail to send the metrics, no notification is sent to us after 70 minutes.
Why might this be happening?

```
{
    "id": "<ID>",
    "name": "Test Monitor",
    "type": "metric alert",
    "query": "sum(last_1m):count:jobs.operation_time{*} by {job_type}.as_count() > 20  (this is an impossible condition)",
    "message": "{{#is_no_data}}\nNo data received\n{{/is_no_data}}@myname@company.io",
    "tags": [
        "tag1"
    ],
    "options": {
        "notify_audit": false,
        "locked": false,
        "timeout_h": 0,
        "silenced": {},
        "include_tags": true,
        "no_data_timeframe": 70,
        "require_full_window": true,
        "new_host_delay": 300,
        "notify_no_data": true,
        "renotify_interval": 0,
        "escalation_message": "",
        "thresholds": {
            "critical": 20
        }
    },
    "priority": 1,
    "classification": "metric"
}
```

Comment: Could you try set `require_full_window` at false? On the UI, this parameter is recommended when the metric is sparsed.

Comment: Already tried it

Comment: The primary reason is that the monitor is never going into no data state even if metric is not getting received for hours. I don't understand why it remains in ok state.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was an issue from datadog side. Its been fixed now.
https://status.datadoghq.com/incidents/jymbdkfx0y0h